# error importing Pandas in python-3.4 unix environment - undefined symbol: pyobject_cmp

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I was using Pandas version 0.16.1 and it was working fine but I wanted to update Pandas to version 0.16.2 so I uninstalled it and reinstalled it using

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas
```

The installation seemed to work fine. However, when I attempt to import pandas

```
import pandas
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path_to_python/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
ImportError: path_to_python/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/hashtable.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: pyobject_cmp

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "path_to_python/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
"extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: path_to_python/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/hashtable.cpython-34m.so:
undefined symbol: pyobject_cmp not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

However:

```
cd path_to_python/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

doesn't work either as there is no setup.py to be found. The error is:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OpenWrapper'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any advice or insight into what could be going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

I tried to install it from source by downloading the package:

```
python setup.py install
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

This time the second command generated a lot of output and successfully completed. However, I still get the same error when I try to import pandas

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to build pandas using clang due to compiler flags. Clang using `C99` model by default which leads to improper compilation of `inline` code used in pandas.

So in my case `CFLAGS=-fgnu89-inline pip install pandas --global-option=build_ext` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested, I was unable to get pandas to install with pip but I switched to using miniconda and installed it with that and it worked fine.